# How to structure a database to take input and assign applicable questions appropriately

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I am creating a database that will feature the following information and need to accomplish the following goals.

## Information:

**Customer Name**
e.g. "Otter's Wash Co"

**Customer's Project Name**.  *One customer could have many projects.*
e.g. "Fur Shur Wash"

**Project Elements** with checkboxes to add them to the report. *Elements may or may not apply to all projects, but the **answers** will be specific to each separate project.*
e.g. "Bus Wash"

---Some project elements would need to have follow-up questions.
e.g. For "Bus Wash", further determine "Dropdown options: School bus, Party bus, Church bus"

#### Goal:

Generate a report that shows the Customer Name, Customer Project (I can do this part so far), and [a list of information based upon the Project Elements] <-- this is the part that I am struggling with how to do.  Especially with how to structure the follow-up questions.

#### For example:

If a Project Element is "Bus: School bus", it would display a specific set of information on the report about school busses.

Answer (score 0):

Your concept of "checkboxes to add them to the report" is likely not practical for 2 reasons:

1. if this is a multi-user database, users will conflict with each other editing the check field
2. since the checks will change for each project, there will not be history

Each project can have multiple elements and each element can belong to multiple projects. This is a many-to-many relationship. This requires a third 'junction' table that associates projects with elements. This junction table can possibly have fields for the additional attributes describing the elements but more likely will need another table.

Possibly another 'junction' table to associate selected element with selected attributes. So the ID of the ProjectElement junction table will be referenced as a foreign key in SelectedAttributes table. Each record will be an attribute associated with the ProjectElement record. This means you will need a lookup table of all possible combinations of element/attribute. Then a cascading (dependent) combobox can be used to limit dropdown list to only attributes applicable to selected element. Requires VBA.

Might want to use form/subform/subsubform arrangement - forms can go 7 deep.

Comment: 1. It will not be a multi-user database, so that's not a problem.  

2. I do want each project to have its own list of elements, and that's probably the biggest issue I've been grappling with is how to set that up.  

The junction table idea would work great, aside from not being sure how I would set up the follow up attributes.

Comment: Another thought, for further clarification, I imagined the elements being basically a list pulled from a template, and each individual project having a list of all elements with whether or not that element will be in this particular project.

Comment: Okay, single-user db. Then the check field could be useful to quickly select a set of elements and batch append records to the junction table to associate with selected project. However, this will require VBA. When you develop a db and code that has specific issue, post question.

Comment: I'm still unclear on how to set up the table structure for the questions-specifically for the follow-up attributes.  Could you shed a bit more light on what your thought was on that?  =)